# Should it be possible to reopen migrated questions?

Tags: discussion, migration, vote-to-reopen

I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405524/how-do-hackers-know-what-and-how-to-hack-a-system-closed), while not particularly outstanding, was relevant and was unfairly closed. However, it seems that because the question was migrated (to superuser?!), I don't have the option of voting to reopen it. This seems odd, and I haven't found anything describing the rationale on meta.

Is this behaviour intentional?

Comment: Here's another example of a question that was incorrectly migrated and now I can't vote to reopen.  In this case it was migrated to meta.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380907/how-do-i-implement-a-voting-system-similar-to-stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought the same thing. I have enough rep to vote to close on SO, but not enough to vote to close on SU. So now it belongs to the SU community just because a few people on SO didn't want it there. With other closed questions you can vote to reopen, so this isn't a real problem. However, as you've pointed out, we don't have that choice.

Comment: Precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is intentional.

If it doesn't belong on superuser but it does belong on SO, the 3K guys can move it back to SO. If it doesn't belong on SU either, it'll be closed there. In neither case is there reason to reopen it on SO.

Comment: It's annoying for people who have lots of rep on one site and no rep on others.  For example, SO is the only site of the 4-5 that I actively participate in.  There was a programming question just today migrated to Meta that doesn't belong there, but since my rep is like 110 here, I can't vote to move it back.

Answer (score 1):

It is intentional, but if you feel it has been wrongly migrated you can flag it for moderator attention. Mods have the power to reopen, unlock, etc. etc. even on migrated questions.

The method for normal users to get it back would be to have the migrated question migrated BACK to the site. Basically play volleyball for a while and eventually the question may settle down on its most proper place.

I prefer that a mod make that call rather than tossing it back and forth indefinitely, however.

Comment: No, I won't flag it. This was just an example of the mechanism. In general, I don't think flagging is reasonable when 5 experienced peers have come to the same (counter)-conclusion, unless there are truly exceptional circumstances. Ultimately, it's up to the community to decide. But I would have voted for it, had that been possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. That question seems like an obvious SuperUser question to me.
2. The behavior *is* intentional.  The question will be automatically migrated to SuperUser, where, if it is deemed to be an SO question, they can vote to migrate it back.

Comment: As long as they don't instead just vote it Off Topic. I was frustrated to see a similar case where the reasonable question about choice of embedded hardware on SO was flung to SU where it was closed immediately as OT instead of flinging it back. I don't have enough rep at SU to do anything to fix it, and on SO there's nothing that can be done to a migrated question.

Answer (score 1):

This particular example is an interesting one. When I ran across it on SU, the first thing I thought (before clicking the title) was some newbie wanted to be like the cool l33t h@x0rs. Then I opened it, read it, saw it was migrated from SO, and said, "WTF?!"

Opening it now again, a few hours later, I see it's getting some really good response. But it's clear that the user was asking, from a programming point of view, how to harden his software. And while 5 people did vote to migrate it, in retrospect I think it was unfairly and unjustly done. I'm not flagging it for mod attention -- but only because it is getting some good answers there.

I do think flagging for mod attention is the right answer in a case like this. But at the same time, in this exact scenario ... How would STRIDE-type guidance for a developer not be programming-related?

SU is not supposed to be our dumping ground!

(BTW, security is a valid topic in all 3 sites -- how to write more secure software in SO, how to protect your network and other assets in SF, and how to protect your individual PC or home network in SU. This one clearly fell into the first bin ... )

Comment: It looked to me like SU was supposed to be our dumping ground.  It caters to a larger community, while SO and SF are more restricted.

Comment: It caters to a larger community, but on more than one occasion Jeff has stated that it is absolutely not a dumping ground for stuff unwanted at the other two communities.

Answer (score 0):

Looks happy enough on Super User; i wouldn't mess with it. But, if you *really* think it was incorrectly migrated, flag the question *on the destination site* for moderator review, and explain why it shouldn't have been moved.