# Line breaks/paragraphs for bounty text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, bounty-remarks

According to [What markdown formatting features are available for Bounty remarks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks) only "mini"-markdown is enabled for bounty text. I just posted a bounty over on [Add an option to recall moved questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66264/add-an-option-to-recall-moved-questions), where I had composed a remark text that looked like this:

> I'd like to see reconsideration of this declined request. (I found this question while composing my own version of it.) As a user with close votes, I can review and reverse any other closing, but not migration. This seems asymmetrical at best, and perhaps even unbalanced: why should four* users have the ability to shove a question off a site without possibility of retraction, when *five* users can't even irrevocably close a question *on-site*?
>
> I don't believe that "Just raise a flag" is good enough as an answer, since moderators frequently state that they prefer to see consensus before taking possibly disputable action. Raising a flag just pits a single user's opinion against five others'. The standard process of collecting five "reopen" votes seems like the ideal way to indicate the desired kind of consensus.
>
> Related: [Should it be possible to reopen migrated questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/should-it-be-possible-to-reopen-migrated-questions)
>   [Allow diamond moderators to reverse question migrations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations)
>
> Note especially Shog9's answer on the second, expressing the opinion that mods *shouldn't* unmigrate generally.
>
> ---
>
> *number of votes required for migration

Note the paragraphs that make this legible instead of the wall-of-text currently present in the bounty box.

Could the bounty remarks display please be upgraded to "small"-markdown, so that such line breaks are preserved?

Comment: ...I don't think you're supposed to write this much.

Comment: @Cody: Well, I suppose that may be true, but given that this many characters are _allowed_, I assumed that they'd be at least somewhat nicely formatted. My other option for adding my own words to the idea are to pretty drastically edit the post (tacking something like this on to the end), and I'm not sure about the advisability of that -- it's still got the OP's name on it, after all.

Comment: I wish we could either add paragraph breaks or shorten the field.  Because [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PyRos.png) is eyeball-numbing, and I suspect the poster didn't realize in advance.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: exactly. [Nor did I realize that before posting.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64226/lme-and-lmer-comparison)

Comment: Related: [Leave newlines intact in bounty messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288635/leave-newlines-intact-in-bounty-messages)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The display of bounty notices with custom text has been updated to preserve double line breaks and to highlight custom text in a more visible and consistent way.

Here is how it will look for single line bounty messages:

[image: single-line message]

Here is how it will look for bounty messages that have multiple lines:

[image: multi-line message]

Each bounty message can have at most four paragraphs. Any subsequent line breaks will be treated as spaces.

Note: This is only applying to double-line breaks. Single-line breaks will not be preserved (will be treated same way as today, like spaces). This has to do with intricacies of the way that this had to be implemented. For *reasons*, handling both single and double line breaks would raise the complexity here to a very large degree (much more than just handling double-line breaks). And since double-line breaks is where the real difference in visibility is felt, that is what was implemented.

Comment: Hey, all right!

Comment: Noice! Is more bounty notice love in the pipeline? Only I have a [pet feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344145) in that direction. :-D I'd share an example bounty notice if the [SEDE was not off-line right now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344277/sede-is-offline), you'll have to fish it out of the database yourself (see the most recent notice for question id 52486985 over on SO), which, incidentally, has several double-line breaks in the original.

Comment: Ah, I'm in luck, I still had the original string in an interactive Python session somewhere; see https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mjpieters/c2911202291c836562d224e065550bcc/raw/585b29247178045401cb4932a71ff6f5973bae74/notice.txt

Answer (score 15):

You can enter 3000 characters when creating a bounty. Forcing all of that into a single paragraph is not useful.

Additionally, even small blocks of text can be clearer and easier to read if they are split up into paragraphs.