# Leave newlines intact in bounty messages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, markdown, bounty-remarks

Bounties allow us to provide a message along with bounties we place, should we deem it useful to include one. I use this myself regularly, and sometimes a decent explanation is warranted so that readers understand what's going on.

However, **bounty messages get their newlines stripped out.** This can impede our attempts to make our bounty messages readable and useful. Just now I wrote  a bounty with 3 paragraphs + a footnote on its own line to maximise its legibility (and could type newlines in the bounty message text input), but after submission the message was compacted into the following:

[image: a rather big chunky bounty explanation paragraph]

It's especially strange that bounty messages can be a whole *three thousand characters long* (enough for a junior essay), while not providing us with paragraphs, a basic building block of legibility:

[image: a couple of lines entered for a bounty message -- below the text box a line says "2881 characters left"]

Not that I think I could ever use the whole 3,000 — the message above was just 850.

**Could bounty descriptions please leave the newlines I write in them intact?**

(Should someone decide to write super-tall bounty messages to abuse this ability, bear in mind moderators can refund bounties; a user making a nuisance is not beyond being acted on.)

Comment: If the purpose of compacting it into a single paragraph is to retain distinctness between the bounty's fixed information lines and the optional message, perhaps the message could be set off with lightweight styling instead of compacting.

Comment: [Line breaks/paragraphs for bounty text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124016)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The display of bounty notices with custom text has been updated to preserve double line breaks, and to highlight custom text in a more visible and consistent way. This is only applying to double-line breaks. You can read more about it (and see screenshots) [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344273).

Comment: That's such a relief! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Taking [SevenSidedDie's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288635/leave-newlines-intact-in-bounty-messages/298566#comment936945_288635) into account, if the reason for not allowing line breaks is for "distinctness between the bounty's fixed information lines and the optional message", **an alternative could be to only allow single line-breaks.**

This allows users to separate their bounty descriptions into sections, while keeping the user description as a single text block.

For example

> This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation
>
> This question has not received enough attention
>
> This is a lengthy bounty description asking that the winning answer meets a specific set of requirements. The question could use some more conversation about things. `\n`
>   Adding a second paragraph could be done with a single-lined line break, which would keep the desired distinction between the "official" text, and the custom description. `\n`
>   This helps increase readability requested by OP, while ensuring that the current method of displaying bounty descriptions isn't altered drastically. `\n`
>   Bounty goes to the answer which best answers the question. `\n`
>   Bonus bounties for extra detail. `\n`

It isn't a perfect solution, but it would give users a bit more control over how their bounty is presented.

Comment: That is still XY problem solving, finding a way to directly solve the problem by distinguishing the information text is a far better solution (different weight, a border, etc).

Answer (score 4):

[Regarding this Q-A session](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120796/why-in-general-must-function-declarations-be-followed-by-a-parameter-set) and [this Q-A session also](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120797/why-in-general-must-function-declarations-be-followed-by-a-parameter-set-exte).

Just an example why this feature is so needed from the last 5 minutes:

Please look at the bounty message I published a few moments ago in its following multi-paragraph version and after that look at the product appearing is one long paragraph:

### Paragraphed version

> This question has a very messy story of migration and merging:
>
> At the start, I published an original question in RC SE, then after it
>   was closed there and me recommended to do so, I Published a new better
>   question here, which is includes more accurate terminology,  is more
>   exampled and more carefully worded.
>
> After asking my new question here, the old one from RC was migrated
>   here without me desiring this so a "salad" of two similar questions
>   was created.
>
> In return I have cloned all question data of the new question into the
>   new one and also asked the mods to migrate all content from the new
>   question to the old question so we would have everything in one place.
>   Well ; it was done.
>
> I now give this bounty because some answers here relate to the old
>   version of the question (migrated from RC) which didn't or at least
>   shouldn't reflect my mind. I ask all answerers of answers to the old
>   question to update their answers per the new question now appearing
>   here after question update.

### Non paragraphed version

> The bounty expires in 7 days. Answers that other users post to this
>   question are eligible for a +100 reputation bounty. JohnDoea is
>   looking for a more detailed answer to this question: “This question
>   has a very messy story of migration and merging: At the start, I
>   published an original question in RC SE, then after it was closed
>   there and me recommended to do so, I Published a new better question
>   here, which is includes more accurate terminology, is more exampled
>   and more carefully worded. After asking my new question here, the old
>   one from RC was migrated here without me desiring this so a "salad" of
>   two similar questions was created. In return I have cloned all
>   question data of the new question into the new one and also asked the
>   mods to migrate all content from the new question to the old question
>   so we would have everything in one place. Well ; it was done. I now
>   give this bounty because some answers here relate to the old version
>   of the question (migrated from RC) which didn't or at least shouldn't
>   reflect my mind. I ask all answerers of answers to the old question to
>   update their answers per the new question now appearing here after
>   question update.”

**What's better? Please, you tell me in comments.**

I find the community's management around this issue as a total mismanagement; I say this humbly with 7 years of experience in the community, offering many bounties myself and having a question about this that was marked as a duplicate of this one.

A non less disturbing problem --- the inability to edit bounty messages, at least within a given time frame.